# javascript html img

Tags: javascript, html, image

im having an img tag in my html
when click on image javascript function alerts the image src path..

```
<image src="angel_wall.jpg" onclick="do_some();return false;" />
```

Comment: What is the question? You want do_some() to output the image path?

Comment: what is do_some(); function doing? Can you post the code here?

Comment: I think he/she wants to know how to alert the image’s `src` value when clicking on it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to alert the image’s `src` path when clicking on it, try this:

```
<img src="angel_wall.jpg" onclick="do_some(this)">
```

And the `do_some` function:

```
function do_some(elem) {
    alert(elem.src);
}
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="imgsrc"/>
this tag in another form, i want to set the value of elem.src to this hidden type, hw?

Comment: @udhaya: instead of `alert(elem.src);`, you can do `document.getElementById('imgsrc').value = elem.src;`

Comment: @udhaya: So you want to change the value of the hidden input when clicking on the image? Try `document.getElementById("imgsrc").value=elem.src` instead of the `alert` call.

Answer (score 1):

It may look like you mean this:

```
<img src="/path/angel_wall.jpg" onclick="alert(this.src);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function do_some(img) {
    alert(img.src);
}

<img src="angel_wall.jpg" onclick="do_some(this);" />
```

Note that 'src' will return the full URL in most browsers. To get only the filename, you'll have to do something like this:

```
var src = img.src;
if(src.indexOf('/') > 0)
    src = src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
alert(src);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<img id="test" src="angel_wall.gif" onClick="alert(document.getElementById('test').src)"  />
```

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="imgsrc"/> this tag in another form, i want to set the value of elem.src to this hidden type, how?

Comment: If you have a new question, then please ask a new question, and don't tack it on as a comment on an answer.

Comment: sorry david, frm now i wil keep this